# properties of ratio and rule of cross multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

If $$\frac{l}{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}+\frac{m}{\sqrt b-\sqrt c}+\frac{n}{\sqrt c-\sqrt a} =0$$
$$\frac{l}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}+\frac{m}{\sqrt b+\sqrt c}+\frac{n}{\sqrt c+\sqrt a} =0$$
Show that $$ \frac{l}{(a-b)(c-\sqrt ab)}=\frac{m}{(b-c)(a-\sqrt bc)}=\frac{n}{(c-a)(b-\sqrt ac)}$$
I try to solve it with all the properties of ratio and rule of cross muliplication ,which I know.
I get $(a-b)$ term in denominator but I can't able to get $(c-\sqrt ab)$ term. I want to solve it on my own  so give me hint to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating one of three terms and get relation between the two terms?

Comment: But how can I eliminate one of three term?by equating two equation with a same term on one side of "="sign?

Comment: Really simple. There is many ways to eliminate one of the term. I use the most straightforward one. As $l$ an example, in first equation, move the item 'm' and 'n' to RHS and multiply two side with donominator in the item 'l' and do the same operation in second equation. And since only 'l' in each one's LHS. Then it is done.

Comment: Yeah I found it thanks for ur hint @ Zack Ni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a,b,c>0,$ let $a =A^2$ etc.

As $(B+C)(C-A)-(B-C)(C+A)=2(C^2-AB),$

$$\dfrac l{\dfrac n{(B-C)(C+A)}-\dfrac n{(B+C)(C-A)}}=\dfrac m{\cdots}=\dfrac1{\dfrac1{(A-B)(B+C)}-\dfrac1{(A+B)(B-C)}}$$

$$\implies\dfrac {l(B^2-C^2)(C^2-A^2)}{2(C^2-AB)}=\dfrac m{\cdots}=\dfrac{n(A^2-B^2)(B^2-C^2)}{2(B^2-CA)}$$

$$\iff\dfrac {l(C^2-A^2)}{C^2-AB}=\dfrac{n(A^2-B^2)}{B^2-CA}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sir how the first step come .please explain it sir

Comment: @SathasivamK, Solving for $l,m$ using http://www.math-only-math.com/cross-multiplication-method.html

Comment: thank you sir for spending your precious time for helping me .due to your awesome  answer I finally find what I doing wrongly .I take co efficient of l as $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}$.